# Assignment by quotient operator?

Tags: c++, delphi, math

I am trying to convert some C++ code to delphi but not sure what this opperator is or how to create it in delphi

```
/=
```

It says in c++ its an Assignment by quotient operator, but no idea what that means?

thanks
Glen

Comment: because "clever" expressions like this, everybody loves Python and hates C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example -

```
 a /= b;
```

is equivalent to

```
a = a / b;
```

Comment: Or `a := a div b;` depending on whether you want integer division or floating point division.